# In R, how can I create a function that can take values from columns using dplyr::mutate, but also still take specific strings as values?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

This is probably a poorly worded question, but bear with me.

I'm trying to make a function in R that converts values based on user-supplied units as strings. Here's a simplified version:

```
conv <- function(val, from, to){
  if(from == "g" & to == "kg"){
    return(val / 1000)
  }else if(from == "kg" & to == "g"){
    return(val * 1000)
  }
}
```

So far, so good. As long as I specifically provide units, it works fine:

```
> conv(val = 10, from = "g", to = "kg")
[1] 0.01
```

However, I would also like to be able to use this to convert values in a data frame where I don't know the units beforehand. Instead, the units would come from columns in the data frame.

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(VAL = round(runif(n = 10, min = 5, max = 50), 0),
             FROM = sample(c("g", "kg"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
             TO = sample(c("g", "kg"), size = 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Here, the units can change so I can't specify them in the function. But if I just run my function via `dplyr::mutate`, I get an error:

```
df_conv <- df |>
+   mutate(VAL_CONV = conv(val = VAL, from = FROM, to = TO))

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `VAL_CONV = conv(val = VAL, from = FROM, to = TO)`.
Caused by error in `if (from == "g" & to == "kg") ...`:
! the condition has length > 1
```

**How can I write a function so that it can take values the user types in directly, but also take values provided in columns via mutate?**

I'd like to keep the solution in base R, but not totally necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `dplyr::case_when`

```r
library(dplyr)

conv <- function(val, from, to){
  case_when(from == "g" & to == "kg" ~ val / 1000,
            from == "kg" & to == "g" ~ val * 1000,
            .default = val)
}
```

Or in base R, nested `ifelse`:

```r
conv <- function(val, from, to){
  ifelse(from == "g" & to == "kg", val / 1000,
            ifelse(from == "kg" & to == "g", val * 1000, val))
}
```

Both `case_when` and `ifelse` give the same results on your test case, but `case_when` would be much more readable when you have multiple conditions.

In `mutate`:

```r
df |> mutate(VAL_CONV = conv(val = VAL, from = FROM, to = TO))
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#>      VAL FROM  TO     VAL_CONV
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>
#>  1    17 kg    kg       17    
#>  2    45 kg    kg       45    
#>  3    27 kg    g     27000    
#>  4    30 g     kg        0.03 
#>  5    34 g     kg        0.034
#>  6    47 g     kg        0.047
#>  7    48 kg    g     48000    
#>  8    44 g     g        44    
#>  9    19 g     g        19    
#> 10    24 kg    g     24000
```

Take user input:

```r
conv(val = 10, from = "g", to = "kg")
#> [1] 0.01
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to either put a functional in your function or in the mutate call in your pipe. For the first, you can change your function the following:

```r
conv <- function(val, from, to){
  Map(\(val, from, to) {
    if (from == "g" & to == "kg"){
      return(val / 1000)
    } else if (from == "kg" & to == "g"){
      return(val * 1000)
    } else { # handles problems with example when from/to are the same
      return(NA_real_)
    }
  }, 
  val, from, to
  ) 
}

mutate(df, new = conv(VAL, FROM, TO))
```

The problem with this is that it returns lists, but is a base R solution. I'd suggest using `purrr::pmap_dbl` instead:

```r
conv <- function(val, from, to) {
  purrr::pmap_dbl(
    list(val, from, to), 
    \(val, from, to) {
      if (from == "g" & to == "kg") {
        return(val / 1000)
      } else if (from == "kg" & to == "g") {
        return(val * 1000)
      } else {
        return(NA_real_)
      }
    }
  ) 
}
```

Finally, you can leave your function as is and do something like this:

```r
conv2 <- function(val, from, to){
  if(from == "g" & to == "kg"){
    return(val / 1000)
  }else if(from == "kg" & to == "g"){
    return(val * 1000)
  } else {
    return(NA_real_)
  }
}

df <- tibble(VAL = round(runif(n = 10, min = 5, max = 50), 0),
             FROM = sample(c("g", "kg"), size = 10, replace = TRUE),
             TO = sample(c("g", "kg"), size = 10, replace = TRUE)) |> 
  rowwise() |> 
  mutate(new = pmap_dbl(list(VAL, FROM, TO), conv2))
```